# How to connect TFS in Visual Studio code without Azure Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, tfs, tfvc, azure-repos

I have just started a project in angular 8 for my work. I am very new to angular. I was suggested to use VS code for development. I have successfully performed the initial installations and also have successfully build couple of html pages. Now i want to commit all the development work to tfs..

I did a lot of research and all the article suggested to use Azure Repo. My work does not have Azure Repo. So my question is, are there any other ways to connect to TFS from Visual Studio Code. And how can I use the suggested method to connect to TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team Foundation Server, Azure DevOps Server, Azure DevOps Services, Visual Studio Team Services are essentially the same thing at different points in time and hosted in different locations. The technology is the same. Azure Repos is the 'new' stand alone name for the Git and TFVC repositories in these products. It's also the name of the extension for VSCode to connect to the Git is TFVC repositories in these products. Naming isn't Microsoft's best known skill.

If your TFS server is configured to use Git, you won't need any extension, git support is built into vscode. The Azure Repos extension will add Pull Request support in Visual Studio Code, but isn't required.

If your TFS server is configured to use TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) you'll need to install the Azure Repos extension as well as  Team Explorer 2019 or Team Explorer Everywhere.

All links to download locations in the blog post below:

- https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/